# JAVA MVC accessing database

Tags: java, sqlite, model-view-controller, dao

I'm studying `java` and `MVC`.
Now I'm trying to connect my software with database `sqlite`.

I have my `Model`:

```
package model;

public class Station {
    private String cnpj;
    private String cep;
    private String razao_social;

    //Constructor
    public Station(){

    }

    public Station(String cnpj, String cep, String razaoSocial){
        this.cnpj = cnpj;
        this.cep = cep;
        this.razao_social = razaoSocial;               
    }    

    //Gets Setters

    public String getCnpj() {
        return cnpj;
    }

    public void setCnpj(String cnpj) {
        this.cnpj = cnpj;
    }

    public String getCep() {
        return cep;
    }

    public void setCep(String cep) {
        this.cep = cep;
    }

    public String getRazao_social() {
        return razao_social;
    }

    public void setRazao_social(String razao_social) {
        this.razao_social = razao_social;
    }
}
```

I have my TableModel:

```
package model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class TableModelStation extends AbstractTableModel{
    private static final String[] columnNames = {"cnpj", "razao_social", "nome_fantasia", "bandeira", "endereco", "bairro", "cep", "imagem"};

    private ArrayList<Station> stations;

    public TableModelStation(){
        stations = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addStation(Station station){
        this.stations.add(station);
        fireTableDataChanged();
    }

    public void removeStation(int rowIndex){
        this.stations.remove(rowIndex);
        fireTableDataChanged();
    }   

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int columnIndex){
        return columnNames[columnIndex]; 
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
       return this.stations.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
       return columnNames.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        switch(columnIndex){
            case 0: 
                return this.stations.get(rowIndex).getCnpj();

            case 1:
                return this.stations.get(rowIndex).getRazao_social();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I want to create the connection to database and also write the sql codes for my model (crud) .  So:

1) Should I create another `package` to separate the connection ?  Maybe an `Interface` ?
2) Should I create something like `StationDAO` to implement my model `CRUD` ?

What is the right way to do it ? Following the `MVC` Rules... I'm really lost.

---

Comment: Yes, Its a better coding standard to use an Interface and separate the implementation. Use a separate class for performing CRUD operation. And, yes its according to MVC rules only. Your controller will look for the DAO classes and then populate the model classes. ANd, then you can display those model classed in view layer.

Answer (score 1):

you can have a dao for connections to database which would be the super class and then `StationDAO` would extend `Dao` connection class

Comment: What about the `SQL Query`. Would it be written inside `StationDAO` ?

Comment: yes it you would have all your `Sql Query` in `StationDao` would be better if you have an interface and that `StationDao` class would implement.

Comment: Thanks man. And where `Controller` get in this ? Who does it communicates with ?